# EF 4.3 with Firebrid Dot Net Provider

Tags: metadata, app-config, firebird, firebird2.5, entity-framework-4.3

### [image]I installed the EF 4.3 And I am getting this error.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.MetadataException'
>   occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.MetadataException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

```
Additional information: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The relationship 'Model.FK_STORE_ADDRESS' was not loaded because 
the type 'Model.STORE' is not available.
The relationship 'Model.FK_USERS_ADDRESS' was not loaded because 
the type 'Model.USER' is not available.
The relationship 'Model.FK_VENDOR_ADDRESS' was not loaded because 
the type 'Model.VENDOR' is not available.
The relationship 'Model.FK_BARCODEPRINT_ITEMSTYLE' was not loaded because 
the type 'Model.ITEMSTYLE' is not available.
```

And goes on to list all the table in the database....

---

The connection string is as follows and it is working fine with EF 4.0

```
metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl; 
provider=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
provider connection string="user=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;database=C:\Pearlpos\Data\Store.fdb;dialect=3;charset=NONE;connectionlifetime=15;pooling=False;packetsize=8192;servertype=0;datasource=localhost"
```

I am trying with a new project and there is no any namespace issues, I believe...
Search didn’t help. Any help is highly appreciated...

Thanks!
Muthu Annamalai

Comment: so it was working with 4.0 and stopped after upgrading to 4.3?

Comment: yes, it is working with 4.0. I tried 4.3 with a separate project (also tried with my original data access project) and getting this System.Data.MetadataException. Schema specified is not valid error

Comment: Another close step toward this problem is, With my existing Data Access Project using Object Context and EF 4.3.0.0, I just installed POCO generator and converted my entities as POCO, then I get the same above error and it seems it is nothing to do with DBContext but with moving classes as POCO.

Comment: Please refer the picture I just added to my question, to explain my problem more clearly.

Comment: any luck with this? I am assuming you've completely deleted the database and re-deployed.  are you using EF code first or model first?

Comment: Not yet. I am using model first. And I believe the problem is with the Firebird DotNet Provider EF SQL generation for POCO Entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out the problem... Partially extended POCO Classes were not included in the model generation and not able to load the Classes. 
I have all my extended Partial classes in the same project, but with different file name, as VS will allow only unique file names.

OK, Finally the problem is the name of the partial class to be exact as the generated class like STORE Cannot be Store, it should be exact as STORE

Thanks everybody...